# Get the list of posts before the date of current post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In a Wordpress site,if an user viewing a post, posted on 01/02/2014,I would like to display posts older than 01/02/2014 in the sidebar.Is there any plugin to do this or any code to get this done by? Any help would be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code results the aal previous post from specific date . get the date of current post  and replace with the date  "2012-03-01" in the code
    $query_string = "order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1";

```
    // Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
    function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
        $where .= " AND post_date > '2012-03-01'";
        return $where;
    }

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in SQL, the query will looks like this:

```
SELECT ID,post_title FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_date` < "2014-02-01 00:00:00" AND `post_type` = "post" AND `post_status` = "publish" order by `post_date` desc
```

Wich means: select `the post id`, `the post title` and `the post date` in `wp_posts` table where `the post_date` is older than `2014-02-01 00:00:00` and the post is `published` and the post is `a post` (not a menu item or something).
In php, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="test">
<?php
global $wpdb;
$query = "
    SELECT ID, post_title,post_date
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_date < '2013-12-01 00:00:00'
            AND post_status = 'publish'
            AND post_type   = 'post'
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
    ";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
// Open an unordered list
echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $results as $result )
    {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<span>'.$result->ID.'</span>'; // Your post ID
        echo '<time datetime="'.$result->post_date.'">'.$result->post_date.'</time>'; // The post date
        echo '<span>'.$result->post_title.'</span>'; // the post title
        echo '</li>'; // Close your list item
    }
echo '</ul>'; // Close your unordered list

?>
</div>
```

It will echo:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>a post ID</span>
        <time datetime="a post date">a post date</time>
        <span>a post title</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>another post ID</span>
        <time datetime="another post date">another post date</time>
        <span>another post title</span>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Of course you can add a `<a href="">` on your post titles and remove the post ID or post date.
I don't know if it's the better method but it works fine :)

Oh, and if you want to echo the result in your sidebar, you should create a new widget :)

Comment: Hmmm I don't know, sorry. I can build a little and simple plugin for you if you want. You should also search on WordPress Plugins.
I found this: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-popular-posts